# SFTP MaxAuthTries error

Tags: server, ssh, sftp

Hello I'm following some instruction on the internet to be able to connect to my server via SFTP using Transfercloud.io but when I try doing test inside ubuntu I'm getting this error

[ubuntu command $ sftp sftpuser@192.168.2.12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWVdu.png)

```
user3036@mcserver:~$ sftp sftpuser@192.168.2.12
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 41: Bad configuration option: maxauthtries
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
Connection closed
```

Comment: This appears to be a setting in the config file that `ssh_config` does not like.  Check `man ssh_config` for the settings that the config file will take.

Comment: AFAIK `MaxAuthTries` is a setting that's supported by the *server* configuration file `/etc/sshd_config` - not the client configuration file